# Отписывание от события

Tags: c#, .net, события

Как то я решил был проверить что будет если из другого объекта подписать метод на событие и потом присвоить переменной которая хранит ссылку на этот объект (из которого брали метод) ссылку на `null`. К моему удивлению метод отработал и вывел все свойства объекта, т.е. казалось бы, что после присвоения переменой ссылку на `null`, этот объект должен был скушать сборщик мусора, но это не происходит следовательно объект ещё в памяти, следовательно это очень плохо. Может есть уже готовой класс который автоматизирует процесс отписывания?

Comment: Нужно не null присваивать, а использовать оператор `-= 
my.MyEvent -= MyEventHandle();`

Comment: @NMD, если не сложно - оформите ответом.

Comment: В WPF можно использовать [WeakEventManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.weakeventmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Он позволяет подписываться на события через слабые ссылки. Соответственно, лишние объекты в памяти держаться не будут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Представим себе сценарий (пример того как *не надо* делать) :

```
static class MyEventClass
{
    public static event EventHandler someEvent;

    public static Delegate[] GetInvokationList()
    {
        return someEvent.GetInvocationList();
    }        
}

class MyClass
{
    void someEvent_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e) { Console.WriteLine("hello"); }

    public MyClass() { MyEventClass.someEvent += someEvent_Handler; }
}

class Program
{
    static void SomeMethod() { new MyClass(); }

    static void Main()
    {
        SomeMethod();

        Delegate[] invokationList = MyEventClass.GetInvokationList();

        for (int i = 0; i < invokationList.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("Subscribed to event in {0} to handler {1}", invokationList[i].Target, invokationList[i].Method.Name);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

На экран получаем результат :

`Subscribed to event in Test.MyClass to handler someEvent_Handler`

Пояснение примера:

В методе, где мы создаем объект этот объект должен был бы быть собранным сборщиком мусора по заверешнию метода, но мы подписали его метод к  статическому ивенту, таким образом создали ссылку на него. Именно поэтому  он не будет собран сборщиком мусора пока не закончится работа программы и сборщик мусора не соберет класс-объект в котором хранится ссылка на этот класс... Наш класс с событием был статическим, но то же происходило бы и с нестатическим классом.

Если бы мы отписались от события вовремя - то такой проблемы бы не возникло. По возможности нужно избегать статические события вообще так как они ведут к "memory leak", но если уж придется - лучше класс наследовать от интерфейса `IDisposable` и в методе `Dispose()` отписываться от всех событий... Потом создавать экземпляр класса только используя директиву `using`, например :

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
   public void Dispose()
   {
      MyEventClass.someEvent1 -= someEvent_Handler1;
      MyEventClass.someEvent2 -= someEvent_Handler2;
      MyEventClass.someEvent3 -= someEvent_Handler3;
   }
}
```

И в программе :

```
using(MyClass instance = new MyClass())
{
   // code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Нужно не null присваивать, а использовать оператор -=

```
    my.MyEvent -= MyEventHandle();
```